# Conditional on columns created dynamically to change data

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

Looking for a way to change the column values based off another column but the columns I want to change were created dynamically so it's not very simple in power query.  Here is the question I asked before to get to this part and now I am stuck again. [Add Custom and Dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825562/add-custom-and-dynamic-columns)

**Table before**

| True/False | DynamicColName1 | DynamicColName2 | ... | DynamicColNameX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |
| False | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |
| False | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |
| False | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |
| True | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |

The ... is just to show the columns can be X long because of the dynamic range of the headers.  The ### represents it can be whatever value.  Doesn't matter in this case.

This is what I want the table to show now.  If True/False col = False then the values in the dynamic columns change to 0. If True then stay the same

**Table after**

| True/False | DynamicColName1 | DynamicColName2 | ... | DynamicColNameX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |
| False | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| False | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| False | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| True | 50 | 60 | ... | ### |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add index, Unpivot, add an if/then statement, then repivot

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1)),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"True/False", type logical}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"True/False", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each if  [#"True/False"]  then [Value] else 0),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom", List.Sum),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: no its not always the column name. thats why this problem is unfortunately very difficult. X just means that the column header can be any different size depending on what the user input.  if you mean that a dynamic column will always be on the far right, then yes that's true. my headers are always true/false then followed by X number of dynamic columns. hope that clears things up

Comment: If the dynamic column is always on the far right then my solution works

Comment: on the 2nd step with the transform column types im getting an error "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation

Comment: You would need to post your code for us to see what you are doing.

Comment: Or perhaps based on your source data, leave off the #ChangedType row and just treat it like text instead of logical, and use ... if  [#"True/False"]  ="False"

Comment: ok i mistyped in the code and i got it to work. what happens though is I only get left with a column named "Custom", which is correct for the right most dynamic column ,but I need all the dynamic columns to be changed to be like "Custom", not just the right one.
Basically DynamicColName1 through DynamicColNameX needs to have that true/false test applied to it. I also need the column name to match the previous name and not just "Custom". Like how I posted the "Table after" in my original post

Comment: code changed to reflect what I should have noticed the first time

Comment: sorry for extended convo but we don't have enough rep to start a convo yet. this code now just leaves me with two rows now and my data summed

Comment: Perhaps your cells are nulls instead of zero? Updated the above code to convert null to zero, since nulls disappear when you do the unpivot, Otherwise it works perfectly with your source data

Comment: thanks a ton. just found a typo (i strongly dislike power query) and thats why it wasn't working.  if you're bored and happen to know the same thing but if there was text in the dynamic columns instead of numbers it would be awesome to know for the future for myself, no worries other wise. thanks again